# AWS IoT - How to create a Web Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, frameworks, aws-iot

I'm new to AWS and web application development.

I have a project where I have a motor and relay connected to a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B.

The Raspberry Pi is to communicate to a web application through AWS IoT to send/receive messages and commands from registered user accounts.

The web application should contain a Sign In page as well as a dashboard.

I wish to also host the web application on the AWS cloud.

I am unsure which of AWS services I should be using and how to use them.

So far, I've only worked out to use AWS IoT Core to communicate between the Raspberry Pi and AWS IoT Core without any web application involved.

Can anyone advise on what services/web framework I might need to know to create a web application that can send/receive commands/messages to/from the Raspberry Pi?

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS Greengrass service. Install the Greengrass Core on your IOT devices (Raspberry Pi) which will install and include the X.502 certificates required to connect to your AWS Account. once you set up the Greengrass, you can install components from Greengrass V2 onto your device from your AWS Account. Deploy a component which would be able to publish messages on an IOT Core topic as and when required by taking data from sensors. Use MQTT protocol for sending messages to IOT Core. Once you receive the messages in IOT Core you can send them to other AWS Services using IOT Core Rules.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Just a couple of questions, am I right to say that 'greengrass components' refer to lambda functions or is it something else? Also, would it be possible to send commands to the greengrass device from the other AWS services? (e.g. a web application on S3)

Comment: Greengrass components can be a lambda function but V2 also supports other applications as components. Yes. You can send commands to a greengrass componnets using iot topics . Listen for that topic inside the greengrass component.